# Access Images just for JWT authorized user - Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, file, authentication, laravel-5, jwt

Using API, I save some image files for authorized users, but It is accessible for anyone that calls my URL.

Is there any way to protect my images and access It just throw my web app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the images inside the /storage/app.

Then you have to create a route like

```
// Route
Route::get('/images/{slug}', controller@showMethod)->middleware('auth:api');

// controller method
public function showMethod($image){

   return response()->download(base_path('path/'.$image), null, [], null);

}
```